# django modeltranslation removes data

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

i am having weird trouble translating [django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) fields with [model translation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation). I want to translate EnumValue field `value`. Code in translations.py Here's

```
class EnumValueTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('value', )

translator.register(EnumValue, EnumValueTranslationOptions)
```

That `value` is in eav/models.py:

```
class EnumValue(models.Model):
     value = models.CharField(_(u"value"), db_index=True,
                             unique=True, max_length=50)
     icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='enumvalue_icons/',blank=True,null=True, max_length=300, verbose_name=_('Icon'))
```

Problem is, i already have a lot of EnumValues in database. When i write this translation code and do migrations, old values just disappear. Objects are still there with other fields like `icon`, but values are empty. If i try add value, that existed before, it says: **value already exists**. If i comment translation code and do migrations, old values are back in place. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have a look at the migration file and the sql structure of the modified database. AFAIK model translations stores the field values in different table.

Comment: I think that too, then how can i copy these values with django?

Comment: See the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440899/django-modeltranslation-cant-get-and-see-original-fields