# Django modeltranslation - can't get and see original fields

Tags: python, django, django-database, django-2.0, django-modeltranslation

I'm trying to use `django-modeltranslation` in my project.

For now, just for `Tag` model with one field - `name`.

I've created and registered `TranslationOptions`, then `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Now I can't access the original `name` text. It seems to be replaced with '' (empty string) but it isn't:

```
In [6]: Tag.objects.first()
Out[6]: <Tag: >

In [7]: Tag.objects.first().name
Out[7]: u''

In [8]: Tag.objects.first().__dict__
Out[8]: 
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x7fc96ad41710>,
 'id': 1,
 'name': u'Sport',
 'name_cs': None,
 'name_de': None,
 'name_en': None,
 'name_es': None,
 'name_fr': None,
 'name_ru': None,
 'name_sk': None}

In [9]: Tag.objects.first().name
Out[9]: u''
```

Do you know how to access the field/s?

**EDIT**

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name=u'Tag',unique=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**translation.py**

```
from modeltranslation.translator import register, TranslationOptions

from tags.models import Tag


@register(Tag)
class TagsTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name',)
```

**settings.py**

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False
gettext = lambda x: x

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', gettext('EN')),
    ('fr', gettext('FR')),
    ('es', gettext('ES')),
    ('de', gettext('DE')),
    ('ru', gettext('RU')),
    ('sk', gettext('SK')),
    ('cs', gettext('CZ')), ]
```

The same problem is in `Admin`:

[image]

Detail:
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#rules-for-translated-field-access):

> Reading the value from the original field returns the value translated to the current language.

This means that `tag.name` doesn't return `tag.__dict__['name']`, but rather `tag.__dict__['name_en']` (assuming English is an active language).

It looks like you have added modeltranslation to an existing project and you have existing data. In order to get modeltranslation to work properly, you need to run `update_translation_fields`, a management command supplied by the app ([documentation link](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#the-update-translation-fields-command)). It will copy the data from original field to default translated field (from `title` to `title_en`).